# Using .splice to remove an item from an array is removing multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have created a page where users can select/ unselect employees. I am using `.push` to add these employees to an array, `users`. I am also using `.splice` to remove the unchecked item from the array. Currently, unchecking the last checked item works fine, however, if I select multiple items and uncheck the first item displayed in the view, it will remove every item from the array.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="addremoveuser(checked, user.ID)"><td>
        <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
    var users = [];
    $scope.addremoveuser = function (checked, id) {
        if (checked) {
            console.log("user selected", id);
            users.push(id)
            console.log("if test", users);
        }
        else {
            console.log("user unselected", id);
            var index = users.indexOf(id);
            users.splice(index);
            console.log("else test", users);
        }
    };
});
```

How can I fix this to only remove the item that was unchecked?

Comment: pass $index instead `addremoveuser(checked, $index)` -> `users.splice(id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
users.splice(index);
```

should be:

```
users.splice(index, 1);
```

Look at documentation:

[Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

**Also, take care what id is.** Is it an ill named **element or actual id of element** in array? Cause if its id of element in array you don't need that `indexOf(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dangerous to splice and mutate your array. One strategy to help with adding/removing users is to simply use `filter`.

```
var users = [];
$scope.addremoveuser = function (checked, id) {
    if (checked) {
        console.log("user selected", id);
        users.push(id)
        console.log("if test", users);
    }
    else {
        console.log("user unselected", id);
        users = users.filter(function(user) {
          return user.id === id;
        }
        console.log("else test", users);
    }
```